# xcode 10, unity, vuforia Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, code-signing, xcode10

I had an App that was running fine before I updated to Xcode 10. Now I am getting this wonderful error. I have tried removing my certificates and reinstalling them, along with doing a clean build. I also did the lock and unlock the key chain trick... all to no avail. I feel like this is something simple i am missing since it worked prior to the upgrade. I have tried all the fixes listed here and none of them helped. 
Oh and it runs fine from Unity.

> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign DC4ECCE551416A76DB9CF4067798E5A0FCFD993C --entitlements /Users/richard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hfbtyhkjckgmiuefkkyamlxrvzrj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/www.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/richard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hfbtyhkjckgmiuefkkyamlxrvzrj/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/www.app